# What is the expected behavior of set-prepend-local-as in BGP?

Tags: network-programming, cisco, bgp

I have a situation as below:

Consider my local AS value is 65002 and the neighbor AS has value 333.
If my AS path shows the value as AS_PATH:65002 333, then on using set-prepend-local-as as 2, what is the expected behavior in AS_PATH value?

Should it be AS_PATH: 65002 65002 333 or  AS_PATH: 65002 65002 65002 333 ?

In other words, if set-prepend-local-as is set, then the value of local AS must prepend the number of times specified(result = number of times*AS + existing AS)?

Please specify if there is any document that specifies the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are using a DATACOM device.

I found this document with sample configs:

https://www.forwardingflows.net/bgp-routing-policy-4050-l3-cpe/

But you should contact DATACOM directly to get the appropriate documentation.

Usually prepend 1, means +1 resulting in your ASN being set twice in the AS PATH.